# Splicing Array Based on For Loop Iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, splice

I am trying to take an array ('selectedWorkshops'), and move objects in it to 'registeredWorkshops'. Then, I also want to remove those objects from both 'selectedWorkshops' and another array simply called 'workshops'.

**See my codepen here: http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/wBVqNN**

Arrays:

```
var workshops = [
  {
    name: 'apples',
    WorkshopId: '19'
  },
  {
    name: 'oranges',
    WorkshopId: '3b'
  },
  {
    name: 'pears',
    WorkshopId: 'x6'
  },
  {
    name: 'pineapples',
    WorkshopId: '55'
  },
  {
    name: 'watermelons',
    WorkshopId: '8v'
  }
];

var selectedWorkshops = [
  {
    name: 'oranges',
    WorkshopId: '3b'
  },
  {
    name: 'watermelons',
    WorkshopId: '8v'
  },
  {
    name: 'pears',
    WorkshopId: 'x6'
  }
];

var registeredWorkshops = [];
```

Function that is supposed to move workshops to 'registeredWorkshops' and remove them from 'selectedWorkshops' and 'workshops':

```
flipWorkshops = function(){
    var numberOfWorkshops = selectedWorkshops.length;
    var X = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfWorkshops; i++ ){
        registeredWorkshops.push(selectedWorkshops[i]);
        for(var j = 0, arrayLength = workshops.length; j < arrayLength; j++) {
            var selectedWorkshop = selectedWorkshops[i];
            var originalWorkshop = workshops[j];
            if(selectedWorkshop == originalWorkshop){
                var matchingWorkshop = j;
                workshops = workshops.splice(j, 1);
                selectedWorkshops = selectedWorkshops.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
};
flipWorkshops();
```

Why aren't the objects being properly spliced out of the 'workshop' and 'selectedWorkshops' arrays like they should be? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s)." http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp So, basically, you're reducing `workshops` to a single object, the removed array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s)." http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp So, basically, you're reducing workshops to a single object, the removed array element.

Instead, change:

```
workshops = workshops.splice(j, 1);
selectedWorkshops = selectedWorkshops.splice(i, 1);
```

...to:

```
workshops.splice(j, 1);
selectedWorkshops.splice(i, 1);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhbvcrmz/1/)

---

Maybe this is what you want:

```
var registeredWorkshops = [];
var flipWorkshops = function(){
    var numberOfWorkshops = selectedWorkshops.length;
    var X = 1;
    for(var i = numberOfWorkshops - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
        registeredWorkshops.push(selectedWorkshops[i]);
        var selectedWorkshop = selectedWorkshops[i];
        for(var j = workshops.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            var originalWorkshop = workshops[j];
            if(selectedWorkshop.name == originalWorkshop.name &&
              selectedWorkshop.WorkshopId == originalWorkshop.WorkshopId){
                var matchingWorkshop = j;
                workshops.splice(j, 1);
                selectedWorkshops.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
};
flipWorkshops();
```

Fixed the `splice`, reversed the loop, as suggested by [jwatts1980](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579148/jwatts1980), moved the `selectedWorkshop` var out of the loop, and compared each object item, rather than comparing objects, since [objects don't compare](http://jsfiddle.net/L6za5wgu/).

[JSFiddle Tweaked](http://jsfiddle.net/nhbvcrmz/2/)

[JSFiddle Object Compare Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6za5wgu/)

Comment: Hey, I think that since items are being removed from the array the `for` loop also needs to be traversed in reverse. `for(var j = workshops.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)`